# Word2Vec, softmax function

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, language-model

I was going term by term through the softmax function for the word2vec (SKIP-GRAM) model.  I found  most definition of these functions to be not 'clear'  so I modified the notation to make sure I understand it.

**Is the following  formulation correct?**

$$P(w_{-t} | w_{t} ; \theta) = softmax(score(w_{-t}, w_t))$$

$$P(w_{-t} | w_{t} ; \theta) = \frac{exp(score(w_{-t}, w_t))}{\sum_{w' \in \theta} exp(score(w', w_{t}))}$$

where:

$w_{-t} =$ context

$w_{t} =$ target word

$score(A,B)$ a measure of similarity between vectors A and B.

$\theta = $ vector representation for all words in vocabulary

In the simplest case:

$$score(A ,B) = A \cdot B$$

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is correct. For the reference you can compare it with the probabilistic model from [Tensorflow "Vector Representations of Words" tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec#scaling_up_with_noise-contrastive_training):

> $$
> \begin{align}
> P(w_t | h) &= \text{softmax} (\text{score} (w_t, h)) \\
> \\
>            &= \frac{\exp \{ \text{score} (w_t, h) \} }
>              {\sum_\text{Word w' in Vocab} \exp \{ \text{score} (w', h) \}}
> \end{align}
> $$

It's the same as yours, but they generalize the condition $h$ as a *history*.

In case of skip-gram, the target word $w_t$ is any *context word* ($w_{-t}$ in your notation) and the history is the *center word* ($w_{t}$ in your notation). You specify $\theta$ explicitly in the condition, but that is usually omitted, because there is only one vocabulary in a given problem.

Comment: Thanks for this! just one question, in the sum term,  does that include scoring w_t to itself?  i.e exp(score(w_t, w_t))

Comment: Yes. Just like ordinary softmax. The denominator contains all terms, including the numerator